# Is using default(string) a common idiom when comparing against the result of Linq xxxOrDefault?

Tags: c#, linq, coding-style

I'm reviewing some code:

```
private static bool TryGetValidatedHost(string unvalidatedHost, out string validatedHost)
{
    validatedHost = _whiteListedHostNames.FirstOrDefault(
        hostname =>
            hostname.Equals(
                unvalidatedHost,
                StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

    return (validatedHost != default(string));
}
```

At first it struck me as odd to compare the validatedHost against the default value for string, I'd have expected this to be a comparison against null.

```
return (validatedHost != null);
```

Then I thought, well this is actually "more correct" - the Linq statement above returns the FirstOrDefault, so it should be compared against the default, it just so happens that the Default for string is null.

Is there a standard pattern for this? Should there be a clear preference, or is it just style, and left to the author?

Comment: IMO, there is technically no difference and it is only a matter of taste.

Comment: IMHO default(string) is worse than null because it will be more confusing to some developers while being semantically equivalent.

Comment: With reference to the votes to close, this question is a bit meta, in that I was really interested in "Is there a sufficient technical difference to matter, or is it just opinion based", rather than the opinion itself. But I'd totally agree it's a bit border line! The answer's helped me nevertheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say it was relatively unusual compared to `null` (or `0` or `new SomeValueType()` for other types) not so much because `default` is so rare as because `null` is so very common. I'd therefore favour `null` for that reason.

I wouldn't consider `default(string)` to be so unusual as to be *weird* though. `FirstOrDefault` of course returns `default(TSource)` because it can be used with both nullable and non-nullable types so it's reasonable for the coder calling it to think "if there's no match it will return `default(string)`" and compare with that, rather than "if there's no match it will return `default(string)` which is `null` because `string` is a nullable type" and compare with `null`.

As such I'd consider it a reasonable stylistic choice. I'd still disagree with that stylistic choice and replace it with `null` if the style guide for the project was up to me and I was reviewing the code, but it's not far off disagreeing about brace style, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's just me, but when I looked at your code, my first thought was that you are comparing the result with an empty string. Don't ask my why, though (it might have something to do with the fact that string don't always behave like "regular" reference types). Not sure how others would react to this, but to me it would be much more obvious what you're trying to accomplish have you used a `null` comparison here.

Comment: Yes that's true also. But that's also kind of the point. As written, you don't have to know what the default is - just that you are comparing the result from the FirstOrDefault to default(String) - as written you don't need to know if the default is Empty, or Null.